# fwrite writes NUL

Tags: php, file, fwrite, nul

I'm trying to write to a file with PHP and this is the code I'm using (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236599/visits-counter-without-database-with-php/18237397?noredirect=1#answer-18237034) to my previous question):

```
$fp = fopen("counter.txt", "r+");

while(!flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  // acquire an exclusive lock
    // waiting to lock the file
}

$counter = intval(fread($fp, filesize("counter.txt")));
$counter++;

ftruncate($fp, 0);      // truncate file
fwrite($fp, $counter);  // set your data
fflush($fp);            // flush output before releasing the lock
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock

fclose($fp);
```

The read part works fine, if the file gets read, it's content is read well, i.e. if the file contains `2289`, then `2289` is read.

The problem is that when it increments and rewrites the value to that file, `[NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL]1` gets written.

What am I missing? Why do null characters get written?

Comment: It's secondary to what you're asking about, but the locking code here is pretty weird. Without the `LOCK_NB` flag, `flock` will block until it can acquire a lock, so it makes little sense to loop waiting for it to return `true`. The only reason it'd return `false` without `LOCK_NB` is if you failed to open the file and are passing it `null` as the first argument, and waiting definitely isn't going to help with that... and the loop means you'll be spewing warnings in an infinite loop in that scenario.

Comment: @MarkAmery I've never been a PHP expert and especially in 2013 I was at the beginning of my career, so that was a beginner mistake for sure :) Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT #2:

Try this with flock (tested)

#### If file is not locked, it will throw an Exception (see added line) `if`(...

I borrowed the Exception snippet from **[this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9863237/1415724)**.

```
<?php

$filename = "numbers.txt";
$filename = fopen($filename, 'a') or die("can't open file");

if (!flock($filename, LOCK_EX)) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Unable to obtain lock on file: %s', $filename));
}

file_put_contents('numbers.txt', ((int)file_get_contents('numbers.txt'))+1);

// To show the contents of the file, you 
// include("numbers.txt");

    fflush($filename);            // flush output before releasing the lock
    flock($filename, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock


fclose($filename);
echo file_get_contents('numbers.txt');

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

The thing you are missing is **rewind()**. Without it, after you truncate to 0 bytes, the pointer is still not at the beginning ([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftruncate.php#refsect1-function.ftruncate-notes)). So when you write your new value, it pads it with `NULL` in your file.

This script will read a file (or create if it doesn't exist) for a current count, increments, and writes it back to the same file every time the page loads.

```
$filename = date('Y-m-d').".txt";

$fp = fopen($filename, "c+"); 
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
    $number = intval(fread($fp, filesize($filename)));
    $number++;

    ftruncate($fp, 0);    // Clear the file
    rewind($fp);          // Move pointer to the beginning
    fwrite($fp, $number); // Write incremented number
    fflush($fp);          // Write any buffered output
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);  // Unlock the file
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: This drove me crazy, I went on a wild goose chase thinking it was character encodings, BOM etc. Turns out it was this! Thanks so much

Comment: This should be the accepted anwser. It explains the why of the `NUL` entries in the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code, a simplified version, but am not sure if it's the best:

```
<?php
$fr = fopen("count.txt", "r");
$text = fread($fr, filesize("count.txt"));
$fw = fopen("count.txt", "w");
$text++;
fwrite($fw, $text);
?>
```