# Test if file is locked

Tags: php, file-locking, flock

In PHP, how can I test if a file has already been locked with [`flock`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)? For example, if another running script has called the following:

```
$fp = fopen('thefile.txt', 'w');
flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: `if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {` is test and set lock. If it return true, file was successfuly locked by this thread, another - file locked by other thread

Comment: And if you use `LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB` it is mark only to write - you can read this file (not in windows)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB, $wouldblock)) {
    if ($wouldblock) {
        // another process holds the lock
    }
    else {
        // couldn't lock for another reason, e.g. no such file
    }
}
else {
    // lock obtained
}
```

As described in the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php), use `LOCK_NB` to make a non-blocking attempt to obtain the lock, and on failure check the `$wouldblock` argument to see if something else holds the lock.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(stream_get_meta_data($fp)['blocked'])
  echo 'file is locked';
else 
  echo 'file is not locked';
```

Comment: I think `stream_get_meta_data(..)['blocked']` has nothing to do with flock. From the docs: 
blocked (bool) - true if the stream is in blocking IO mode. See stream_set_blocking(). https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php

Answer (score -3):

Check it like this:

```
if (!flock($file, LOCK_EX)) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf('File %s is locked', $file));
}

fwrite($file, $write_contents);
```

Comment: This will block, means, it's going to wait until the handle is unlocked. It won't throw an Exception.