# How to lock a file against external processes

Tags: php, file-locking

I need to create a lock file that can not be deleted by other scripts or processes. I tried this:

```
    $f = fopen($pidFile, 'w');
    fwrite($f, getmypid());
    flock($f, LOCK_EX);
```

but any other process started from the current user can delete the `$f` file even if the file handle is still opened by the running script. How to solve this problem and prevent others (i.e. **non-PHP processes too**) from deleting the file? And the lock to be released automatically when the process exits? All similar questions ends with an *RTM flock()*, but none of them answer how to lock a file against external processes.

OS is `Linux 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64`

Comment: `flock` is "advisory", not strict. Use [additional check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771824/php-test-if-file-is-locked) before doing anything with file in your scripts. This will work if it's about your own PHP scripts. If it's about external processes - then `flock` can not save the case.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I need to lock the file to prevent deleting from external processes (i.e. non-PHP too)

Answer (score 6):

`flock` on Linux uses "advisory locking" by default, which means it does not prevent any other processes from manipulating that file. See the note in the PHP Manual.

> flock() uses mandatory locking instead of advisory locking on Windows. Mandatory locking is also supported on Linux and System V based operating systems via the usual mechanism supported by the fcntl() system call: that is, if the file in question has the setgid permission bit set and the group execution bit cleared. On Linux, the file system will also need to be mounted with the mand option for this to work.

Also see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/mandatory-locking.txt

> A file is marked as a candidate for mandatory locking by setting the group-id bit in its file mode but removing the group-execute bit. This is an otherwise
>   meaningless combination, and was chosen by the System V implementors so as not
>   to break existing user programs.
>
> Note that the group-id bit is usually automatically cleared by the kernel when
>   a setgid file is written to. This is a security measure. The kernel has been
>   modified to recognize the special case of a mandatory lock candidate and to
>   refrain from clearing this bit. Similarly the kernel has been modified not
>   to run mandatory lock candidates with setgid privileges.

Also mind the warning:

> Not even root can override a mandatory lock, so runaway processes can wreak
>   havoc if they lock crucial files. The way around it is to change the file
>   permissions (remove the setgid bit) before trying to read or write to it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But how to implements this in PHP to solve my problem?

Comment: @AlexanderPravdin try https://books.google.de/books?id=mCpnlNYzqOQC&lpg=PA247&ots=qAWSgskqZ6&dq=mandatory%20file%20locking%20php&hl=de&pg=PA246#v=onepage&q=mandatory%20file%20locking%20php&f=false

Comment: Thank you, but the flock() function do not lock file against external processes (as I can see what is explained in this book). But pages from 249 and further are hidden and require to buy the book.

Comment: @AlexanderPravdin not sure, might be possible with http://php.net/manual/en/function.dio-fcntl.php but dont take my word for it. A better option might be file swapping as explained in that book.