# Can i make variable accessible in two files without include?

Tags: php, variables

i want to create variable in file a.php like

```
 <?php
 $string = "hi";
 ?>
```

and in file b.php make this code work without including a.php

```
<?php
echo $string;
?>
```

edit : one of files (a.php should work on cli and do some operations(it will be on while true loop) and b.php should open on visitors side on web interface

thanks ;)

Comment: It's possible, but it would be really hacky. Stick with include / require, it's what they're there for. Other options outside PHP would include, e.g. environment variables. But that depends on your use case.

Comment: @Jonnix I wouldn't say `$_SESSION` is hacky - though I wouldn't advise it's use for this..

Comment: what's your beef with include's?

Comment: You can use `$_SESSION` maybe, open it, add the value in file 1 and get it in file 2

Comment: @treyBake Depends on the use case. I didn't read the question as saying that the 2 files are independently run. If they are run on their own, then sure, $_SESSION is a perfectly valid option in general.

Comment: you can pass it by using query as parameter in url and retrive it using `$_GET`

Comment: Why dont you want to inlcude / require the file, maybe there is a reason that can be solved by a better way than hacking the importing of files? I think using session vars depends on the use case. Session vars should not be used to hold globals or something similar. I think it will help to get some more info about the use case.

Comment: a.php should work on cli, and do some operations, with include it will lost it's data that already have collected, and b.php should open on visitors side!

Comment: Wait. So a.php is a cli script that you make sound like data is passed or generated, which you then want to access in b.php which runs in a completely different env (i.e. cli vs web). Sounds like a database (or other data store) may be what you're looking for rather than includes or sessions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scale a variable in two file without using **Include** or **Require**, the only way is to use **cookies** or **session** variables, or if the situation permit it, using **GET** or **POST** data.

But I guess in your case you just want to use the variable from another file easily.

Using **session variable** :

In your **a.php**

```
<?php
if(!session_id()) session_start();
$string = "hi";
if(!isset($_SESSION['hello'])) {
    $_SESSION['hello'] = $string;
}
?>
```

And you can use it in **b.php** :

```
<?php
if(!session_id()) session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['hello']){
    echo $_SESSION['hello'];
}

?>
```

Comment: i can't use sessions because on of files (a.php) should run in command line :( and file b.php should load on users side

Answer (score -1):

A other hacky way: You can create a "transfer" file to write (**file_put_content($fileName, $fileContent,  LOCK_EX)**) and read (**file_read_content($fileName)**) from the other files. Its important that you flag the file for writing. Only one process should write the file at the same time.

Check file is locked: [Test if file is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771824/test-if-file-is-locked)

Comment: it's good way to do it but, read and write will slow down code and also i want to transfer variables like arrays, thank you <3 i will try to find some other ways

Comment: The file can contain json or a serialized object. After all you can use a separate service like memcached (https://memcached.org/).

Comment: Overhead? Its the same as the session file was read/write and when it is a included php file the opcache will auto cache it.